# How to avoid smart card selection popup when accessing windows-my using Java

Tags: java, windows, certificate, keystore

I want to access the certificates in the user cert store of Windows ("Windows-MY") using a key store in java.
Here is the code I use:

```
    KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-MY", "SunMSCAPI");
    ks.load(null, null);
```

Unfortunately, executing this code does open a popup from windows, asking the user to select a smart card.

After clicking cancel in this popup (several times), the keystore is built properly and the certificates can be accessed.

Disabling the Smartcard Service under Windows Services helps, but then Smartcards cannot be used any more (we use Smartcards in another use-case).
How can I access the Windows store without having this popup?

Answer (score 3):

In my case, what happened was that the smartcard software (or some smart card middleware I installed, I'm not sure) wrote a registry entry: [more info here](https://www.chilkatsoft.com/p/p_280.asp)

Registry path: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography\Defaults\Provider (on Windows Xp and 7, both 32 64 bits, not tested on Win8)

[image: offending entry]

Deleting this registry entry solved my pop-up problem. Just for caution, export the entry before deleting it so, if something goes wrong, you can restore it. I had to delete and restore several entries before finding the offending one.